# Setting popup dimensions in Chrome launchWebAuthFlow?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

The official documentation [here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity.html#method-launchWebAuthFlow) doesn't mention that, but it looks like support for setting width & height for launch flow windows has been added - See [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132143#c19).

So I tried this from a packaged app on Chrome 29 (stable) and 31 (canary):

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
  url: MY_FACEBOOK_OAUTH_URL,
  interactive: true,
  width: 400,
  height: 300
}, function(){});
```

And got this:
`Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'width': Unexpected property, Property 'height': Unexpected property.`

Anyone knows if this is actually possible? The default dimensions don't play well with the Facebook popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change you are referring to affected experimental identity API. Setting dimensions of the window with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow is currently not supported. Please [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) in chromium bug database if you would like that functionality to be introduced in chrome.identity API.

Comment: It's now supported but only in an experimental API - http://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/trunk/apps/experimental.identity.html

Comment: 10 years later... any updates on this, I am hitting the same issue but can find no Experimental API.....