# chrome extension chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow - how to set size of popup window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

How do you set the popup size from `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` : https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-launchWebAuthFlow

This question: [Setting popup dimensions in Chrome launchWebAuthFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958944/setting-popup-dimensions-in-chrome-launchwebauthflow) from 10 years ago asks same question, and it sounded like it was being developed, but I can see no way to do it 10 years later.

Is it possible now?  Or do you have to roll your own auth flow ui just to set the size?

I have full control of the auth page, but  adding a size like you do for other chrome ext popups....

```
body, html {
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
}
```

does nothing, and

```
<script >

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      window.resizeTo(500, 500);
    })

  </script>
```

throws lots of CSP errors

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http://localhost". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Even with `unsafe-inline` in the manifest as a test still throws the error in the auth window.

any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Came to this solution for now using `chrome.windows.onCreated` and `chrome.windows.update`

```
function resizeAuthWindowOnCreated(width:number, height:number) {
  
    chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function resizePopup (win) {
      
      if(win && win.id) {
        // get current auth win pos, or default to center of screen
        const {
         top:t = Math.round(window.screen.height/2), 
         left:l = Math.round(window.screen.width/2), 
         width:w = 0, 
         height:h = 0 
        } = win;
        
        // Resize and re-center the auth window
        const opts = { 
          top: Math.round((t + h/2) - height/2),
          left: Math.round((l + w/2) - width/2),
          width,  
          height,  
        };

        chrome.windows.update(win.id, opts);
        chrome.windows.onCreated.removeListener(resizePopup);
      }
    }, {windowTypes:['popup']})
}
```

And then use it like...

```
resizeAuthWindowOnCreated(550, 700);

const response = await chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
  url: authURL,
  interactive: true
});
```

Not ideal, but works for now....

Comment: The size has been always hard-coded in the source of the API. A possible workaround is to use chrome.windows.onCreated + chrome.windows.update.

Comment: Correction, it was supported for a while in 2012 while it was experimental: https://crbug.com/132143

Comment: @wOxxOm I just came to the same conclusion - not the best solution, but works, ill update the question with an example....